# How to add style class to a created ComponentRef in Angular 5?

Tags: css, typescript, angular5

I am trying to add a CSS class to a component immediately after I create it using `ViewContainerRef` and `ComponentFactoryResolver`. I want to be able to set the class based on what other Components have already been added to `myViewContainerRef`.

```
export class ContainerComponent {

@ViewChild('myContainerRef') myContainerRef: ViewContainerRef

constructor(private factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
            private renderer: Renderer2) {}

addComponent() {
  const componentFactory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SomeBaseComponent)
  const newComponent = this.myContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory)

  // SomeBaseComponent has been added successfully to myContainerRef
  // Want to add CSS class to the newComponent
  // None of the following statements are adding any styles
  if( someLogic()) {
    this.renderer.addClass(newComponent.location.nativeElement, 'my-css-class')
    this.renderer.addClass(newComponent.el.nativeElement, 'my-css-class')
    this.renderer.setStyle(newComponent.el.nativeElement, 'background', 'yellow')
  }
  }
}

export class SomeBaseComponent {

  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {}

}
```

Is there a better way to go about trying to add the style programmatically? Is there something else I can inject into `SomeBaseComponent` to be able to add the styles I want at this point, or should I set flags on the `newComponent.instance` and have the base component be in control of what styles to set on itself?

Answer (score 0):

You should add another @ViewChild which will have a **read** of `ElementRef` type.

```
@ViewChild("myContainerRef", {read: ElementRef}) elementRef: ElementRef;
```

To set the **class** attribute, you should use the following.

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.setAttribute("class", "test")
```

**Note:** I will advised putting the creation logic inside an `ngOnInit()` method, inside of a custom `addComponent()`.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion worked, but I ended up going a different direction to try and reduce confusion. Adding the styles during the `addComponent()` method directly would have hid where the styles were coming from.


So instead I gave each of the `SomeBaseComponent`s a layout type during `addComponent()`, and had the derivatives set their own `ngClass` based on the layout during their `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: Any time you find yourself manipulating the native element `class` attribute while writing an Angular component, you need to step back and think about how you got there.  There are so many "Angular-ish" ways to style components and this is not one of them.

Comment: And what is your suggestion to achieve this, @Coderer?

Comment: You can use the `:host` pseudo-element in your component CSS, or the `@HostBinding("style")` decoration.  If you can move the style down into the component itself then you can use the `[ngClass]="{foo: someCondition}"` or `[class.foo]="someCondition"` directives in its template.

Comment: Thanks @Coderer, `@HostBinding("style")` was the right answer for me